# Is this pattern correct "to cut wood into logs"

Tags: verb-pattern

Is "to cut wood into logs" correct? If yes, how natural is it?

> Woodcutters cut forest trees into logs.

Comment: Sounds perfectly natural to me (American English).

Comment: For me, it is not idiomatic in English.

Answer (score 1):

A woodcutter is a very old-fashioned term, something you might find in a fairy tale. The term is often  found in fairy tales.
[woodcutter in the context of fairy tales](http://www.mainlesson.com/display.php?author=mulock&book=fairy&story=daughter)

**A woodcutter would be said to cut down a tree** (first step) and then (second step) **chop wood** or **chop it** into smaller pieces (logs): to chop wood means to take a larger piece of wood and reduce it in size to be used in a fireplace.

In contemporary English, the term is logger. And trees are **cut down** in English.

The contemporary term is lumberjack or logger. [lumberjack or logger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumberjack)

Loggers or lumberjacks cut down trees to be made into logs. The logs are not made by the loggers, in fact. Once the tree is cut down, the timber [a tree after it is cut down] can be chopped up into logs.

Woodcutters chop down trees and then chop the timber (tree trunks or large branches) into smaller pieces, or logs. Personally, I would not describe all this activity as woodcutter "cutting trees into logs." Trees are cut down  or chopped down.

Answer (score 0):

> Woodcutters cut forest trees into logs.

As the commenter wrote:

"Sounds perfectly natural to me (American English). – godel9"

Agreed.